# merge and create array from two different sized arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I need to take two arrays, and combine them to look like this. Not sure how.  Here are the two arrays.

```
$items = array( 'activity', 'photos');
$activity_subitems = array ('var1', 'var2', 'var3');
$photo_subitems = array ('var1', 'var2');
```

I would like it to be in an array like this;

```
$query_vars = array( 
    'activity' => 'var1',
    'activity' => 'var2',
    'activity' => 'var3',
    'photos' => 'var1',
    'photos' => 'var2'
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the resulting array is a dictionary, you can't, because you are creating more than one same Key for multiple Values. If it is not a dictionary, rephrase the question please.

If what you want is to create something like this:

```
Array ( 
    [activity] => Array (
        [0] => var1
        [1] => var2
        [2] => var3
      )
    [photos] => Array (
        [0] => var1
        [1] => var2
      )
)
```

Then you can do it like this (assuming this is PHP we are talking about):

```
$items = array( 'activity', 'photos');
$activity_subitems = array ('var1', 'var2', 'var3');
$photos_subitems = array ('var1', 'var2');

$query_vars = array();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $query_vars[$item] = ${$item.'_subitems'};
}

print_r($query_vars);
```

Also, keep in mind that the value names for the subarrays are generated from the values from the first array by appending `_subitems` to them.
I have renamed the variable `$photo_subitems` to `$photos_subitems` for this to work, because that is the value from the `$items` array.

Comment: That is what I want.  Would you please elaborate on the use of '&$item' in the foreach.  I have never seen that before. What exactly does that do?  When is it appropriate to use it?

Comment: Actually, in this example you don't need it. This is a reference variable. You can read more about that [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php), [here](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). It is basically the same as a pointer in C/C++. This way, if you change the value of `$item` inside the loop, it will actually **change** the value of the element it *refers* to in the `$items` array. If you don't use reference, any changes will not be reflected in the original array.

Comment: You don't need that in this example, so you can just write `$items as &$item)`, because you are not modifying the `$item`, you are just creating a whole new array with those values, so passing by value has more sense than by reference. I will update my answer to remove this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recognize the language, but in a pseudo-code kinda way

```
query_vars = new array();
for ($i in $items) {
   for ($j in $i+'_subitems') {
      query_vars.add($i, $j);
   }
 }
```

keeping in mind that you're creating the variable $j from from the value stored in $items (located @ $j) and a static field `_items`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are working with PHP. First off, you will not be able to have multiple values with the same key in your array, but if you wish, you can make the values keyed to arrays themselves.

```
$items = array( 'activity', 'photos');
$activity_subitems = array ('var1', 'var2', 'var3');
$photo_subitems = array ('var1', 'var2');

$query_vars = array();
$query_vars['activity'] = $activity_subitems
$query_vars['photo'] = $photo_subitems
```

If you would like to have an array where the strings themselves start with photo/activity, but where it is not a dictionary (again, can't have duplicate keys), you can do something like the following:

**NOTE:** the eval() function is generally considered unsafe, and is not recommended for use in just about every language I know, and this is also true for [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). Use the following at your own risk, but as long as you have strong control over what text can be placed into an `eval()` call (i.e., no user input is ever used), it should be somewhat safer. I get the impression you might want to use the values in `$items` to say what variable to use when building your result.

```
$items = array( 'activity', 'photos');
$activity_subitems = array ('var1', 'var2', 'var3');
$photos_subitems = array ('var1', 'var2');
$query_vars = array();

foreach ($items as &$item) {
    foreach (eval('$'.$item.'_subitems') as &$subitem) {
        $query_vars[] = $item.' =>'.$subitem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `photos` in `$items`  vs `photo` in `$photo_subitems`. Its his typo, but can confuse the author.

Comment: @Lawrence thanks, updated second solution to reflect the conflict